# Is there a way to restore everything I had before I corrupt the upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: upgrade, files, restore, screen-corruption

When I was upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, I mistakenly terminated the installation window and lost everything and I corrupted the system.  So, is there a way to restored the Programs (including the settings), files, ect...?

Comment: If you want an answer please provide as much information as possible. What error do you get on boot, how you terminated the installation etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well as you can see the installation (upgrade) remove every file so they are lost. The program I used (to get my files backs after an accidentally Hard drive clean) photorec .

It's a program that is run from the terminal to retrieve files from a partition.

To install it:

> sudo apt-get install testdisk

To execute it:

> sudo photorec

Follow the next steps that appear you and you could retirieve your files

**NOTE: It will include all the files like the ones that were at the other directories in /**

Also it may not work because it has the 14.04 there but you could give it a try